# Is there a way to use WebSockets with older IIS?

Tags: iis, websocket, windows-server-2012

Windows 2012 license prices are very high if one needs to use one or two dozens. WebSockets are supported under IIS 8.0, which can be run under an OS >= Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012. I wonder whether it is possible to enable WebSockets on older IIS?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: @LexLi, recently I have bought a WebSocket support for Apache, which has a PHP script which generates an IPC file and then loops forever, listening to messages and then sleeping for 250 milliseconds. I have a PHP extension and an Apache module to handle those events under the hood. I was able to make this work on my end yesterday. I wonder whether something like this is possible under older IIS if I add a module and implement the handler. If not, why not?

Comment: IIS is not Apache. I have no more to add.

Comment: @LexLi, that is true, but I wonder whether there is a solution for IIS as well.